# PHP Simple HTML Dom & Memory

Tags: php, dom, zend-studio

PHP Simple HTML Dom problem
Hi I have about 40 urls which I looping through within the loop I have the following

```
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);
    $html =  file_get_html($value);
```

After 7 or 8 loops it appears to stop working. I'm thinking this is a memory issue but I can not tell.
Has anyone had the same or similar problem.
I am using Zend studio and have set a break point in the loop. it is hit for the first 7 or 8 but then nothing happens.

Any help much appreciated,

Comment: try to increase the php memory limit

Comment: you should get an error if its a memory issue, assuming you have  errors on, you can check in the loop how much memory is used with: memory_get_usage()

Comment: thanks - I'm using the local debugger in zend studio 8. I'll have to do a search to find how I can do that.

Comment: thanks for that - memory is goin up and up so I'm guessing it is a memory issue

Comment: you should get a fatal error if memory is exceeded, it should not just 'hang'

Comment: Hmm sure has got me stumped - runs for 6 or 7 then just stops. head scratching stuff - any hint on how to catch the error? Tried try and catch but nothing.

Comment: what's the memory usage show? how much memory has php been allocated? do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: I'm running a php script in zend studio debug mode - any idea how to find out the memory limit?

Comment: phpinfo(); will tell you the settings

Comment: right but I am using the internal debugger in zend studio - can not call phpinfo() - thanks,

Comment: Assuming your HTML files are valid then it really does sound like you've unearthed a bug in PHP's garbage collection.  Unsetting your $html object should free the memory it's occupying.  It might be worth submitting a bug report on this, but before you do so, try to verify that the HTML being parsed is indeed valid.  Also try parsing each file one at a time instead of in a loop to verify that it's the culminative effects of parsing a collection of files and not just one particular file causing problems.